# Android - How do I load a layout into a View?

Tags: android

No example seems to work. I have inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/latest_info_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</View>
```

And in the activity:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View latest_info_content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_info, null);
View latest_info_container = (View)findViewById(R.id.latest_info_container);
((ViewGroup)latest_info_container).addView(latest_info_content,0);
```

And the app crashes - the error is `android.view.View cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`.
When I change the `<View>` to `<ViewGroup>` in the layout, the error is `can't instantiate class android.view.ViewGroup`

Comment: Well, it seems that you want to put a parent into a child... sounds like pedopornography!!

Comment: How so? latest_info_container is the parent and the first parameter of addView is the child.

Comment: Your question title... **How do I load a Layout into a View?** should be: **How do I load a View into a Layout?** It was a joke, of course.

Comment: I thought I was trying to load a layout (R.layout.latest_info) into a view (R.id.latest_info_container) which would make the view the parent and layout the child. I don't know Android well enough to understand humor, I'm tearing my hair out here

Comment: A layout is a **container** (parent): LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, TableLayout, ...; while a View is **usually** a component (child): TextView, ImageView, View... Then there are **particular** "Views" that can be containers too: ScrollView, ListView, GridView, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your View by a Linear/RelativeLayout, it should works:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/latest_info_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</RelativeLayout>
```

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View latest_info_content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_info, null);
RelativeLayout latest_info_container = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.latest_info_container);
latest_info_container.addView(latest_info_content,0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Only `ViewGroup`'s can have children. `View`'s can't.

Comment: And ViewGroups apparently can't be instantiated, just their subclasses like RelativeLayout. Therein lay the rub.

Comment: @TimSim Yes, that's true. The `ViewGroup` class is abstract. And you can't instantiate abstract classes.